# Get all data from 3 table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I want to get all the data through the username from the 3 tables but I can not.

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$res=$conn->query("select * from posts,tbl_view,tbl_user where posts.idpost=tbl_view.post_id AND 
username='$username'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you missed  the condition for join tbl_user with post.

Assuming your fk column is user_id, your query could be:

```
select * 
from posts
INNER JOIN tbl_view  ON posts.idpost=tbl_view.post_id
INNER JOIN tbl_user ON posts.user_id = tbl_user.id 
WHERE tbl_user.username='$username'
```

You should not use the old join syntax based on comma separated table's name and where condition but use the explicit join syntax

And you should avoid the use of php var in sql. You should use prepared  statement and parameter binding (to avoid SQL injection risk).